# Despite adding QSA to mod_rewrite, $_GET still returning empty variable

Tags: mod-rewrite, get

**UPDATED 2/1/13:** This question is really holding me up from getting some work done, so if anyone else has a suggestion, It'd be much appreciated.

I'm trying to make `domain.com/notalone/viewpost/5/` act as `domain.com/notalone/viewpost.php?id=5`

My current .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^notalone/viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Currently, the page loads properly when you visit `/notalone/viewpost/5/` but **it does not pass `$_GET['id']`**

**Things I've Tried**:

- Adding `Options -Multiviews` ---> *Results in a 404*
- Using `Rewritebase /` ---> *No effect*
- `RewriteRule ^viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA]` ---> *No effect*

Comment: I should add, the rewrite code is working perfectly! It's just the empty variable that seems to be giving me issues.

Comment: Add this at the top of the script to display all server variables: `<?php echo var_dump($_SERVER) . "<br /><br />"; ?>`.

Comment: Done, but what exactly am I looking for?

Might it be this?

`["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" `

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` should be `/viewpost/5/`. That's what you are trying to match with the regex.

Comment: `["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(21) "/notalone/viewpost/5/"`

Comment: There you are. The regex should be `^notalone/viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$`

Comment: It seems the answer should be obvious at this point, but this is my first endeavor into rewrites, and so I'm still a bit off evidently. I've modified my mod_rewrite to what you've suggested, however now I'm getting a 300 Multiple Choices.

`The document name you requested (/notalone/viewpost/5/) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
Available documents:

/notalone/viewpost.php/5/ (common basename)`

Comment: Here: `RewriteRule ^notalone/viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$  /viewpost.php?id=$1  [QSA]` No need to modify anything else.

Comment: the page is showing up, however I'm back at square one: still no variable.

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^notalone/viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$  /viewpost.php?id=5 [L]`. If still no variable, the script `viewpost.php` is not in the right place or is doing nothing. Notice the back reference $1 is replaced with `5`.

Comment: Went back to the 300 error at this point. ID does not show up at /notalone/viewpost.php/5 (which is the page it suggests).

`viewpost.php` and `.htaccess` are both in the "notalone" folder. the full path is www.trporfolio.net/notalone/

Comment: Got rid of the 300 error. Still not passing the variable though. This is getting beyond frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `viewpost.php` is in the notalone folder, but you htaccess assumes it is in the root.

So I think it should be:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^notalone/viewpost/([0-9]+)/?$ /notalone/viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

(Note that I added the multiviews, because that will be your next issue. The fact that the old url worked was because of multiviews.)

Comment: I've since figured out the problem, and the problem was a directory mix-up just as you said! I moved the whole website to its own host when it was all done and sure enough the problem disappeared as soon as I did that! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found your solution. Have a nice day.